# TableViewを並び替えた後のデータ更新とCellの更新について

Tags: swift, ios, tableview

こんにちは。
調べてもどうしても出てこなくて困っています。
UITableViewの並び替えた時のセルの更新について質問させていただきます。

---

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //一時的に保存
    let cellData = cellDatas[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cellDatas.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    cellDatas.insert(cellData, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)   
}
```

と、このようにデータソースを入れ替えるようにすると思うのですが
この後にどうしてもtableViewのセルの更新を行いたくて、

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //一時的に保存
    let cellData = cellDatas[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cellDatas.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    cellDatas.insert(cellData, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    //リロードを追加
    tableView.reloadData()  
}
```

このようにするとセルのデータは確かに更新されるのですが、
 ≡ をつかんで離した時の挙動が早すぎて不自然です。そこで

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //一時的に保存
    let cellData = cellDatas[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cellDatas.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    cellDatas.insert(cellData, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    //リロード開始
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath, toIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    //リロード終了
}
```

と書いてみたのですが今度は正常にセルがリロードされません。

---

セルをリロードしたい理由につきましては、セルの持つ部品のプロパティに現在のCellの行番号を保持させて置きたいのです。(以下を ≡ を動かした後もう1度呼びたい)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //この中でcellの持つ部品のプロパティに値を設定する
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.view.row = indexPath.row
}
```

---

---

---

おかげさまで解決しました。ありがとうございます。
この質問の下にコメントを残したのですが、マークダウンに慣れていなくて、見にくくなってしまいました。
コードだけでも書き直したいと思います。申し訳ございません。

CustomCellのプロパティにクロージャをもたせておいて

```
var buttonTapAction = {}
```

セルを返却するメソッドでViewController内のメソッドを渡して

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CustomCell 
    cell.buttonTapAction = {self.buttonTapAction(cell)} 
}
```

同じViewController内のメソッド(ここではbuttonTap‌​Action(_:))を用意

```
func buttonTapAction(cell:TextTableViewCell) { 
    let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row 
    //rowを使った処理
}
```

と別の部分で取得することができました。

Comment: `cell` に `indexPath` の情報を持たせておかなくても、必要なタイミングで [`indexPath(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614881-indexpath) を呼び出すことで、`cell` から `indexPath` を取得することができます。

Answer (score -1):

質問者さんの意図を完全に理解した自信はないのですが、リロードを遅らせたいのでしたら、GCD（Grand Central Dispath）等を利用して、遅延処理することになるでしょう。

*Swift 3*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cellData = cellDatas[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cellDatas.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    cellDatas.insert(cellData, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    // 1秒遅らせてリロード
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1), execute: {tableView.reloadData()})  
}
```

*Swift 2*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cellData = cellDatas[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cellDatas.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    cellDatas.insert(cellData, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    // 1秒遅らせてリロード
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (NSEC_PER_SEC * 1))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatchQueue, {tableView.reloadData()})
}
```

Comment: コメント、回答いただいた方々、本当にありがとうございます。
Swift3 も合わせてコメント助かりました。
`//データを返すメソッド
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.buttonTapAction = {self.buttonTapAction(cell)}
}`
とデータを返すメソッド内でcellを引数に渡して同じViewController内のメソッド(ここではbuttonTapAction(_:))を用意し、そこで
`func buttonTapAction(cell:TextTableViewCell) {
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
    }`
と取得することができました。